# If a vector field is conservative then is it path independent?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am studying vector calculus and I am having trouble with the idea of path independence.

Is it necessarily true that if $F=(P,Q)$ (a vector field in $\Bbb R^2$) is conservative, then $\oint \limits _c F \Bbb dr =0$ and thus $F$ is path independent?

Or can we have $\oint \limits _c F \Bbb dr =0$ with $F$ not being conservative but still path independent?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a mistake: vector fields have nothing to do with path independence (because they have nothing to do with paths). Line integrals, on the other hand, do.

If $F$ is conservative, then clearly its line integral is $0$ along any piecewise-differentiable closed curve. You probably want to ask whether the converse is true: can we have $\oint \limits _c F \Bbb d r = 0$ for every closed piece-differentiable curve $c$, and yet $F$ not be conservative? Well, think of what "conservative" means: $\int \limits _c F \Bbb d r$ should depend only on the endpoints of $c$. Consider two curves $c_1$ and $c_2$ with the same endpoints. Let $\bar c_2$ be the curve $c_2$ with the opposite orientation. Note that the curve $\bar c_2 \cdot c_1$ obtained by joining $\bar c_2$ to $c_1$ is a closed piecewise-differentiable curve, therefore $\oint \limits _{\bar c_2 \cdot c_1} F \Bbb d r= 0$ by assumption. But this integral is $\int \limits _{\bar c_2} F \Bbb d r + \int \limits _{c_1} F \Bbb d r$ and since $\int \limits _{\bar c_2} F \Bbb d r = -\int \limits _{c_2} F \Bbb d r$, puting things together gets you $-\int \limits _{c_2} F \Bbb d r + \int \limits _{c_1} F \Bbb d r = 0$, or $\int \limits _{c_2} F \Bbb d r = \int \limits _{c_1} F \Bbb d r$, which shows that the line integral of $F$ does not depend on the curve joining the endpoints of $c_1$ (or $c_2$ for that matter).

So no, you cannot have $\oint \limits _c F \Bbb d r = 0$ for every closed piece-differentiable curve $c$, and yet $F$ not be conservative; $F$ must be conservative.

Answer (score 0):

The integrals of the vector field along different path will yield the same result, if that's what you mean - so the integrals on closed paths are always zero. But I daresay it's not possible to call a vector field "path independent".

It's possible that an integral on a closed path will yield 0 even if F is not conservative - however, F is conservative if and only if the integrals on all possible closed paths yield 0.